# MapFromSkeletonPoint obsolete in Kinect

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, kinect, msdn, kinect-sdk

I ran into an issue with the Kinect SDK because some code I want to use is utilizing outdated classes. I am building it out as a x86 program in VS2010 in Windows7. The current Kinect SDK is at version 1.7.

**The file I am working with can be found here:**
[a link](https://github.com/fatihboy/Robosapien/blob/master/RobosapienKinect/Viewers/KinectSkeletonViewer.xaml.cs)

**This is the code I am working with specifically to fix the errors:**

```
       private Point GetPosition2DLocation(DepthImageFrame depthFrame, SkeletonPoint skeletonPoint)
    {
        DepthImagePoint depthPoint = depthFrame.MapFromSkeletonPoint(skeletonPoint);

        switch (ImageType)
        {
            case ImageType.Color:
                ColorImagePoint colorPoint = depthFrame.MapToColorImagePoint(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y, this.Kinect.ColorStream.Format);

                // map back to skeleton.Width & skeleton.Height
                return new Point(
                    (int)(this.RenderSize.Width * colorPoint.X / this.Kinect.ColorStream.FrameWidth),
                    (int)(this.RenderSize.Height * colorPoint.Y / this.Kinect.ColorStream.FrameHeight));
            case ImageType.Depth:
                return new Point(
                    (int)(this.RenderSize.Width * depthPoint.X / depthFrame.Width),
                    (int)(this.RenderSize.Height * depthPoint.Y / depthFrame.Height));
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("ImageType was a not expected value: " + ImageType.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**The obsolete classes it uses are:**
Microsoft.Kinect.DepthImageFrame.MapFromSkeletonPoint(Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonPoint)
&
Microsoft.Kinect.DepthImageFrame.MapToColorImagePoint(int, int,     Microsoft.Kinect.ColorImageFormat)

**These are the class methods I am supposed to use in the fix, I just don't know how to do that yet:**

```
public DepthImagePoint MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint (
     SkeletonPoint skeletonPoint,
     DepthImageFormat depthImageFormat
)

public ColorImagePoint MapDepthPointToColorPoint (
     DepthImageFormat depthImageFormat,
     DepthImagePoint depthPoint,
     ColorImageFormat colorImageFormat
)
```

**Here is the error report I get when I build the RobosapianKinect folder:**

Warning 1   The field 'Com.Enterprisecoding.RobosapienKinect.MainWindow.kinectStream' is assigned but its value is never used   C:\Robosapien\Robosapien-master\RobosapienKinect\MainWindow.xaml.cs 50  24  RobosapienKinect

Warning 2   'Microsoft.Kinect.DepthImageFrame.MapFromSkeletonPoint(Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonPoint)' is obsolete: 'This method is replaced by Microsoft.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint'    C:\Robosapien\Robosapien-master\RobosapienKinect\Viewers\KinectSkeletonViewer.xaml.cs   172 42  RobosapienKinect

Warning 3   'Microsoft.Kinect.DepthImageFrame.MapToColorImagePoint(int, int, Microsoft.Kinect.ColorImageFormat)' is obsolete: 'This method is replaced by Microsoft.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint'  C:\Robosapien-master\RobosapienKinect\Viewers\KinectSkeletonViewer.xaml.cs  177 50  RobosapienKinect

Warning 4   'Microsoft.Kinect.DepthImageFrame.MapFromSkeletonPoint(Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonPoint)' is obsolete: 'This method is replaced by Microsoft.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint'    C:\Robosapien-master\RobosapienKinect\Viewers\KinectSkeletonViewer.xaml.cs  172 42  RobosapienKinect

Warning 5   'Microsoft.Kinect.DepthImageFrame.MapToColorImagePoint(int, int, Microsoft.Kinect.ColorImageFormat)' is obsolete: 'This method is replaced by Microsoft.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint'  C:\Robosapien\Robosapien-master\RobosapienKinect\Viewers\KinectSkeletonViewer.xaml.cs   177 50  RobosapienKinect

Warning 6   The field 'Com.Enterprisecoding.RobosapienKinect.MainWindow.kinectStream' is assigned but its value is never used   C:\Robosapien\Robosapien-master\RobosapienKinect\MainWindow.xaml.cs 50  24  RobosapienKinect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obsolete methods replaced. Code clean-up & reformat.
You can get latest version from https://github.com/fatihboy/Robosapien

Answer (score 3):

`MapToColorImagePoint` and `MapFromSkeletonPoint` methods are obsolete. Obsolete methods are old and not used anymore. Instead they are replaced with another method which pretty much does the same thing.

In this case `MapToColorImagePoint` is replaced with `MapDepthPointToColorPoint` and `MapFromSkeletonPoint` is replaced with `MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint`. You should use these methods instead of old ones.

For mapping skeleton point to depth point :

```
DepthImagePoint depthPoint = this.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skeletonPoint, this.Kinect.DepthStream.Format);
```

For mapping depth point to color point :

```
ColorImagePoint colorPoint = this.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint (this.Kinect.DepthStream.Format, depthPoint, this.Kinect.ColorStream.Format);
```

Comment: Your answer seems to work. It throws no errors. I still have to hammer out the "The field 'Com.Enterprisecoding.RobosapienKinect.MainWindow.kinectStream' is assigned but its value is never used" error to be sure.

Comment: I used #pragma warning disable to disable the error. Still trying to get full functionality from software. Will let you know when it works. Will try to find better solution to error.